# Can all computable numeric functions on church numerals in ski-combinator calculus be expressed using only completely evaluated terms?

Tags: computability, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

Let a term in ski-combinator calculus be called "complete" if every primitive is partially applied (so all S's are applied to at most two arguments, all K's to at most 1, and all I's are not applied).

So for instance:
`S(II)I` is not complete, but it can be rewritten as `SII` which is complete.

`SII(SII)` is not complete and cannot be rewritten in any way to make it complete.

`S(K(SII))(S(S(KS)K)(K(SII)))` is complete, but can't be used for much because when applied to any `<x>`, it results in a term `SII(S(K<x>)(SII))` which is usually incompletable (unless `<x>` happens to be something like `KI`).

Some complete expressions for arithmetic operations on church numerals:

successor (\x -> x + 1): `S(S(KS)K)`

addition (\x -> \y -> x + y): `SI(K(S(S(KS)K)))`

multiplication (\x -> \y -> x * y): `S(S(KS)(S(K(SI))(S(KK)(SI(K(S(S(KS)K)))))))(K(K(KI)))`

predecessor (\x -> x - 1): `S(K(SI(K(KI))))(S(SI(K(S(K(S(K(S(SI(K(KI)))))K))(S(S(SI(KK))(SI(K(KI))))(S(K(S(S(KS)K)))(SI(K(KI))))))))(K(S(SI(KK))(K(KI)))))`

(the last one took me a long time to figure out.  Basically, start with a pair (true, 0) and then apply n times "if the head is true, change it to false, otherwise add one to the tail" and then at the end extract the tail)

Are there computable operations on church numerals which cannot be expressed as complete terms?

---

Note: I'm not counting functions like Collatz-length since that's only well defined on a not-known-to-be-computable subset; no skirting the computability requirement by restricting the function to an uncomputable subset of inputs.

Comment: You might want to cross-post your question here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seems to me that what you are calling a “complete” term is the same as one that is in normal form.  Is that correct?  If so I think the answer to your question is ‘yes’ because of the theorem that says that if a term has a normal form, then the normal form can be obtained by normal-order evaluation of the term.  I will elaborate tomorrow.

Comment: That seems reasonable.  To Mock a Mockingbird mentioned normal form for numbers (using a different numbering system besides Church numerals), but I didn't know it applied more generally.

Comment: But I don't see how the theorem you mentioned applies to my problem. Isn't it possible that an operation (such as Collatz Length) has no normal form? (Note: the question is about functions on Church Numerals, not functions applied to Church Numerals)

Comment: @MJD Please elaborate?